# Is there any use of clear:right here

Tags: css

I have this HTML code: http://jsfiddle.net/Lgj1s5km/

```
<div class="clear">Div1 with float:left and clear:right</div>
<div class="float">Div2 with float:left </div>
```

and this CSS:

```
div {
  border:1px solid #ff9900;
  width:120px;
  height: 120px;
}

.clear {

  float:left;
  clear: right;
  }

.float {
  float: right;
}
```

As far as I understand, the way `clear: right` does is that floating elements are not allowed on the right side. In case they are, the element to which "clear" is applied to goes to a new row and starts a new document flow.

In this example, however, it's not physically possible for `div.clear` to go to a new row because it's preceded by a new element. If I reverse the order of the 2 `<div>` tags, however, this will all work fine.

My question was, is it possible to still get `div.clear` to go to a new row, despite the fact it's in front of `div.float`?

Comment: As you already said, clear resets the flow of the elements after it in the DOM. In order to position them they way you want you probably have to change the order in the DOM - this is how I'd do it. You can apply positioning, but this is not a really dynamic approach. Flexboxes might offer the functionality you want, you might want to check them out.

Comment: Indeed. `clear` clears the `float`s that are before it, not the `float`s that come after. So the question is, do you really want to move Div1 down? If so, then you can use positioning or translation, or even a large top margin. You can't use clear, because there's no float to clear!

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you have any other elements which may then be affected by your positioning of `div.clear`, but if not, then you can give `div.clear` *the impression* of being on the next row down, simply by declaring a `margin-top` equal to the height of `div.float` plus the height of `div.float`'s top and bottom borders:

```
.clear {
float: left;
margin-top: 122px;
}
```